# Поиск в txt файле

Tags: php

Имеется .txt файл, в котором записан текст. Хочу сделать скрипт который будет находить и извлекать строки по условию:

`текст_который_ищем:а-здесь-любой-текст;`

То есть искать я буду текст **текст_который_ищем** , а в ответ мне должна прийти строка: **текст_который_ищем:а-здесь-любой-текст;**

конец строки это символ **;**

Буду благодарен за помощь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно понял:

```
$file = ''; // Путь к текст.файлу

$need = 'текст_который_ищем';

foreach (file($file, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES|FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES) as $line) {
    if (preg_match("~{$need}.*~", $line, $string)) {
        echo str_replace($need, "$need:", $string[0]);
    }
}
```